# Do views create new rows and store data on every request in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just wanna know do views create rows (with an existing view query) every time data is requested or do they just store existing data on it and keep updating with new changes?

Answer (score 3):

Views (in general) do not create and store data.  They are simply SQL code that is substituted into another SQL statement.

Some databases (although not MySQL) support a type of view called a *materialized view*. Such a view does store data and is updated when the underlying tables change.

Comment: they generate whole new rows when we request data? Or they simply update with non existing data on view?

Comment: @salinkunwar: Yes, a query against a VIEW executes the view query, and  accesses rows in the underlying tables, each time the view is referenced. A view definition doesn't cause any rows to be stored. It's really just a query that gets executed when it's referenced. A stored view definition is equivalent to an inline view. i.e. `CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT t.* FROM t; SELECT v.* FROM v;` is equivalent to executing `SELECT v.* FROM (SELECT t.* FROM t) v`.  The difference is that with the latter, w're including the view definition inline. In the first, we're storing the definition and referencing it